# Using appsettings, but "ConfigurationSettings" method is obsolete

Tags: vb.net, appsettings, windows

I've trying to access an appsettings key value in my vb.net 2.0 web application.

I've put the key in the app.config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="DownloadURL" value="http://<myURL>/" />
</appSettings>
```

I've followed the instructions [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/config.aspx), and it says that I need to access this key like so:

```
URL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("DownloadURL")
```

But I get the following message:

> Public Shared Readonly property
>   AppSettings() As
>   'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection'
>   is obsolete: 'This method is obsolete,
>   it has been replaced by
>   System.configuration!System.configuration.configurationmanager.AppSettings'

I tried to replace the old method with the new one, but it does not exist.

Strange, since I've done a similar thing with a web app and it did exist there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a reference to System.Configuration.dll.

[Here's an explanation.](http://www.gibedigital.com/blog/configurationsettingsappsettings-obsolete)

Comment: Ok. It's "Imports" because it's VB though.

Comment: You'd only need to use a using/import statement if you aren't using the full namespace of the class, you shouldn't need it if you include the System.Configuration part.